# How would I include this Case Statement within a Where?

Tags: sql, case, hue

I am a newer user of SQL but trying to write a query with a where to limit date, category and 3 actions.  I also need a case statement to include times for blank values, a time displayed and ND (for no displayed times).  I ran the where and it worked, so the problem is in the Case statement and I can't figure it out!!

```
SELECT *
FROM raw_data.mobileappsec
WHERE date_partition = '2023-03-20'
  AND type_cat = 'Resort'
  AND (action_v11 = 'Action1'
  OR action_v11 = 'Action2'
  OR action_v11 = 'Action3'),
CASE
  WHEN search_time_mvvar1 IS NULL THEN 'Blank'
  WHEN search_time_mvvar1 = 'ND' THEN 'ND'
  ELSE 'Time'
END;
```

Comment: you need to comapre4 the result of the CASE WHEN  with a column or text

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking, but it sounds a bit like the `CASE` *expression* (**not a statement!**) should go in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT *,
   CASE
      WHEN search_time_mvvar1 IS NULL THEN 'Blank'
      WHEN search_time_mvvar1 = 'ND' THEN 'ND'
      ELSE 'Time' END
FROM raw_data.mobileappsec
WHERE date_partition = '2023-03-20'
   AND type_cat = 'Resort'
   AND action_v11 IN ('Action1','Action2','Action3');
```